# How do I set the sizes of my thumbnails when inserting a [gallery]?

Tags: images, gallery

A really simple thing, yet my images are uploaded as about 500px wide, I have them selected as full size, yet when I use the [gallery] shortcode, it crops the thumbnails to 100w x 75h.  This isn't even the thumbnail size I have set in my media settings!  My page is [here](http://davidspeightphotography.co.uk/wordpress/publications-2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `[gallery size="thumbnail"]`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode